# Building Go Lang database 'tiedot'

Tags: go

The GO Package github HouzuoGuo/tiedot does not successfully build.  Has any one successfully
built this package?

It complains the the package github GeertJohan/go.rice is needed and not available.

However it is on Github.  I am at a loss how to build this package.

Comment: Post an error, please.

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote (and the rest of the document) is worth a read if you're just starting out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `go get` to download / install packages:

```
┌─ oneofone@Oa [/tmp]                                                                                                            
└──➜ go get -v -u github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot
github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot (download)
bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext (download)
github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice (download)
github.com/daaku/go.zipexe (download)
```